# Maxthon browser: Google integrated login page is misbehaving

Tags: browser, login, webkit

I use Maxthon to login Gmail, Google, and use that sign-in across other websites.

Unexpectedly, the new login page is not behaving properly when I am trying to login(in the same account) after I logged out properly.

Google is detecting my previous email address, and asking for password only.
When I am entering password, it is doing NOTHING. The page isn't crashed.

Environment:

- Windows 7 Enterprise
- behind corporate firewall, but Google services aren't blocked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some analysis, and retrying on other browsers, i decided that the cookies(from google.com.*) that are saved by Maxthon browser, are corrupted.

As, Maxthon has no user-friendly option to clear cookies only, I had to work under the hood for work around.

- Open the login page
- Open Developer tools. Main_Menu --> Tools --> Developer's tool.
- Click "Resources" tab, navigate to "Cookies" section, select Google.*
- Delete each of the line individually
- Reload the page with "*CTRL+F5*", not just F5.

Now the page loads with no "preloaded" email address. Now, i could sign-in easily.

Comment: @Burgi ha ha, i didn't know that should i accept my own answer or not. "Accept"-ing it now. thanks for the reminder.